# Log file manipulation using python

Tags: python

I'm the following log file structure. I want to find out the maximum response time and want to print the log file which is having the highest response time(R.T) using python 2.7.11.

**The structure of my log file:**

```
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed R.T
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed R.T
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed R.T
```

**Code Used:**

```
file =open(r"log.txt","r")
for line in file:
line_array = line.split(" ")
print line_array[10]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
R.T
R.T
R.T
```

Until now I could able to print all the response time from the log file. I couldn't able to get the highest response time (R.T) out of it.

Help me to find the highest response time with the whole log file printed as an output.

Answer (score 1):

Staying close to your own code and assuming it indeed gives the output as you describe:

```
file =open(r"log.txt","r")
highest = -1
for line in file:
    line_array = line.split(" ")
    highest = max (highest, float (line_array[10]))

print (highest)
file.close ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the actual response time (R.T) that will be in the R.T label (I guess), save it and then get the max one. So your code should look like:

```
file = open(r"log.txt","r")
rts = []
for line in file:
    line_array = line.split(" ")
    rts.append(float(line_array[10]))

#Now find max
max_rt = max(rts)
print "Max R.T is :", max_rt
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with an empty list BEFORE your loop

```
response_times = []
```

Instead of just printing the line element, add it to this list WITHIN the loop:

```
response_times.append(line_array[10])
```

Finally, print the maximum AFTER /outside the for loop:

```
print max(response_times)
```